# Windows 10, how do I create a .reg file to toggle enable/disable ipv4,6?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

On my Windows 10

Assuming that the ethernet properties settings can be changed via the registry, I want to disable/able the ipv4,6 items. One .reg file to make them disabled and another .reg file to make them enabled.

How do I make these 2 .reg files?

Comment: You can use ipconfig /release all for this. To reconnect: ipconfig /renew. No need of registry and PowerShell, just cmd. These commands are shorter than the PowerShell commands.

Comment: These two links should be helpful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows  https://uncomplicatingit.com/microsoft/disable-ipv6-from-the-registry/